# Show() not working with <li> tag

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I have this dropdown box I creating using Foundation 4.

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="pipeline" class="small secondary radius button dropdown" >Select a Pipeline</a>
  <ul id="pipeline" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown ">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="2d">2D Pipeline</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3D Pipeline</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

What I want to do is when a user clicks on 2D Pipeline, it should show a `div`. Here is my script. The `div` is hidden on document load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href*='teams_pipeline.html']").removeAttr("id");
  $("#2d_div").hide();
});
$("#pipeline li a#2d").click(function() {
   $("#2d_div").show();
});
```

This script does not currently work

Comment: ID should never be started with numbers, try using some string.

Comment: Just as a note to everyone who will come here saying that `id` should never start with a number: This is no longer a restriction on `id` in the [W3C working draft spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) for HTML5.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the ID attributes?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here, that code makes no sense. If you want a helpful answer please try to describe what you want it to do a bit better.

Comment: "does not work" ????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

You remove the id on pageload, try removing that bit:

```
$("a[href*='teams_pipeline.html']").removeAttr("id");
```

from the code and it should work.
and maybe hide the div in your css, using javascript in this context seems unnecessary, like
set

#2d-div{ 
display:none
}

?

Comment: If I remember right the single quotes in the attribute selector mess things up.

Comment: It's not related to the drop down. It's just removing id attribute from a link I have in the file.

Comment: Yeah, but why do you have that? the $("#pipeline li a#2d").click(function(), has nothing to refer to if the id attr is removed

Answer (score 0):

move the `click` handler piece within the `$(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href*='teams_pipeline.html']").removeAttr("id");
    $("#2d_div").hide();

    $("#pipeline li a#2d").click(function () {
        $("#2d_div").show();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/7cmAY/)

also consider hiding the div initially with CSS instead of jQuery